# IntelliJ IDEA why I don't see the method in import dialog? (have in project and if put with copy-past to class, it's accessible). Maven+Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, settings, hamcrest

I use 15.0.4 IDEA Coomunity edtition (same trouble was for at least for 2 versions).
Actually, I clicked something wrong and need help. :-)
So...
In pom.xml I have in list of my dependencies:

`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>`

And when I add in any method someting like that:

`AssertThat(%someVariable%,is("someExpectedValue"))`

And tries to auto-import there are only possibilities to auto-import from org.junit.
But if I add

`import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;`

The assertion code works correctly.
So, the problem is: my auto-import in IDEA don't offer to import hamcrest classes (before it worked, and I guess there are some settings or project properties issue...).

p.s. code completion does not work for assertThat (hamcrest) too. Instead of it i got a lot of SeleneseTestBase.assert%%.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java then select Imports. There you can set static imports